# One-to-many between different DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

There are two entities: User (post's author) and Post

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

And two DbContext for them

```
public class AppIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public AppIdentityContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityContext> options) : base(options) { }
}

public class ForumContext : DbContext
{
    public ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Post>(ConfigurePost);
    }

    private void ConfigurePost(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
        // Author is ApplicationUser from AppIdentityContext
        // As far as I know, this won't work
        builder.HasOne(p => p.Author)
            .WithMany(u => u.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorId);
    }
}
```

Can I somehow configure the automatic filling of the `Post.Author` field with EF Core in this case?

P.S. I found this (seems like solution), but I don't understand it. 
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4595#issuecomment-189534388

Comment: You can't have the same entity in two contexts. I never worked with ASP.Net identity but I think I'd never change anything in the `IdentityDbContext`, just use the defaults. Much easier to kick it out when one day you're going to change the authentication strategy. Then in other contexts you can include a *second* user class that maps to the ASP.Net user. I think it's nearly always nothing but the user that's the linking pin between the authentication scheme and the rest of the application.

Comment: @GertArnold, I don't quite understand, could you show an example?